# how to remove line break on the last text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to remove line break for example in a1 column i have 3 lines which is separated by line breaks and on the last line there is extra line break which i want to remove please note that sometimes there is more line breaks on the last line that i need to remove and i need to maintain the line break separates on each line except for the last line i have tried below formula but i cannot find the solution to maintain line break on each line

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")

dfddgfggfgfg(char)10
jhjkhkhjhhjk(char)10
hkjhkhjhhhjh(char)10
```

Comment: It took me a while but now I see that you only want to remove the line breaks at the end, not in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove a trailing CHAR(10) if it exists:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=CHAR(10),LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

It first checks if the last character is CHAR(10), and if it is it trims it off.

**Edit**
Make sure you get the format on the cell correct. You'll need to click **"Wrap Text"** for the cell you put the formula in. To test it, you can just put in "=A1". If all the breaks are gone, then it's a display issue!

Comment: this will remove all the line breaks

Comment: @Sorceri No it won't. It will only remove line breaks on the very end

Comment: @Sorceri this is a good formula it will only remove the last one.

Comment: @ScottCraner when I tested it the line breaks were removed.   Tested with Sub AddVal()
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "l" & Chr(10) & "l" & Chr(10) & "l" & Chr(10)
End Sub  to add the value to the cell and then used the formula above, the result was lll with no line breaks.

Comment: Is your cell with the formula set to wrap text? @Sorceri

Comment: Make sure you click "Warp Text" for the cell you put the formula in. Otherwise Excel will even make `=A1` all go on one line.

Comment: @Kate66 make an edit to your answer that you need to add the wrap text - Good catch Scott!

Comment: The problem is that there may be more line breaks at the end as per @ramon, so that won't be enough, you would have to repeat and nest all the logic again.

Comment: @ Andrew thats correct some has more line breaks at the end

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but this will remove all the line breaks in the last 3 characters of the cell:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,3),CHAR(10),"")
```

If you think there may be more than 3 line breaks at the end, or that a line won't be as short as 2 characters, you may increase that value (in both places).

Also, as stated in the other answer, make sure that in the cell's properties, the `Wrap Text` option is checked.

Comment: it is not working &SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,3),CHAR(10),"") is not replacing all the end line break this one works =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3) but im still trying if i can remove the line breaks without counting how many line breaks i need to remove

Comment: How many line breaks do you have at the end? My function removes all breaks that it can find in the last 3 characters of the cell. What does `RIGHT(A1,3)` return in your case?

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all the Char(10)s at the end regardless of how many:

```
=IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),""),1)=CHAR(10),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),""))-1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),""))
```

Comment: @ Scott Craner i have tried ur formula special char still there at the end

Comment: This works quite well unless there are two consecutive new lines in the middle of the cell, in which case it removes them. @ramon, what special char at the end?

Comment: @ Andrew its line break at the end i want to remove it and it should be more or it doesn't matter how many line breaks at the end